# Удаление строки таблицы HTML посредством нажатия на кнопку в ячейке этой строки. JS

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется таблица, ее часть:

```
<table class="in" id="in">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="str_in">
                        <td class="num_in">2</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" step="1" name="l_in[]" min="0" max="12000" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" step="1" name="c_in[]" min="0" max="10000" autocomplete="off">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="id_in[]" maxlength="12">
                        </td>
                        <td class="del_in" onclick="delRow();">
                            X
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Есть кнопка которая создает новые строки такого же содержания и нумерует их.
Часть функции которая задает параметры последней ячейки таблицы как кнопку:

```
var td5 = document.createElement("td")
    td5.setAttribute("class", "del_in")
    td5.setAttribute("onclick", "delRow();")
    td5.appendChild (document.createTextNode("X"))
```

Далее мне необходимо по нажатию кнопки удалить строку в которой она находится.

Пытался сделать что-то такое:

```
function delRow(){
  var td = this;
  var i = td.parentElement.rowIndex;
  td.parentElement.deleteRow(i);
}
```

И такое:

```
del_in.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var td = this; // элемент который вызвал функцию
  var i = td.parentElement.rowIndex;
  cell.parentElement.deleteRow(i);
});
```

del_in тут просто по аналогии с теми примерами которые находит естественно не работает.

На самом деле это одини из десятка вариантов которые я пробовал. Просто они остались не удаленным и я их показываю что бы показать хоть что-то. Были варианты с передачей в функцию  event и другие всяческие попытки повторить найденные решения. Главным камнем преткновения стал доступ к элементу вызывающему функцию, т.е. к ячейке дабы просто удалить ее родителя(строку). Я начал читать про замыкания и области видимости переменных в JS, и вроде все понятно, обращаеся к переменной, если ее нет в области видимости функции JS должен пойти искать выше, но почему тогда this возвращает window? Разьве this не должно быть в области функции если есть тот кто ее вызыввает зачем она идет выше до самого window?

Приветствуются любые решения данной проблемы. Даже костыльные лишь бы уже заработало. JQuery я не знаю, но если что буду разбираться, во сяком случае если что прошу дать комментарии по его использованию если таковой будет использован.

P.S. Понимаю почему JS многие недолюбливают. После С++, С#, Python и т.д. выглядит он мягко говоря не дружелюбно)))

Comment: оформите код нормально, что б его можно было править.

Comment: для function delRow(){  ....надо сделать простые манипуляции ...1. `function delRow(el){` .... и 2. `onclick="delRow(this);"`  ...  теперь в `el` будет ссылка на элемент

Comment: с `del_in.addEventListener("click"` не ясно, т.к. непонятно что такое `del_in` и откуда он взялся

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, спасибо в el действительно теперь нужный элемент! Мне кажется я уже что-то такое пробовал))? Я еще имею некоторые проблемы, но думаю теперь я быстро разберусь! Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, старался выдрать тот минимум, который необходим для обозначения проблемы. Иначе - свалка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал кнопку добавления, для удобства.
По нажатию на эту кнопку в tbody вставляется HTML при помощи [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).
Затем при нажатии на импровизированный крестик, вызывается функция delRow, которая поднимается к родителю и удаляет его.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#add_new_row');
const table = document.querySelector('.in > tbody');
let count = 1;

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const row = `
    <tr class="str_in">
      <td class="num_in">${count++}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" step="1" name="l_in[]" min="0" max="12000" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" step="1" name="c_in[]" min="0" max="10000" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="id_in[]" maxlength="12">
      </td>
      <td class="del_in" onclick="delRow(this)">
        X
      </td>
    </tr>
  `;
  table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
})

const delRow = (el) => {
  el.parentElement.remove()
}
```

```html
<button id='add_new_row'>Добавить новую строку.</button>

<table class="in" id="in">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```